# How to apply an NUnit Attribute to An Assembly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

According to the documentation you can apply the [NUnit timeout attribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Timeout-Attribute) to an assembly:

> The attribute may also be specified on a fixture or assembly, in which
>   case it indicates the default timeout for any subordinate test cases.

The challenge I am running into is that they give no indication of how to apply the attribute to an assembly on that page or anywhere else I can find in the documentations.

I tried using `[SetupFixture]` and decorating that with the attribute but that did not seem to take. Has anyone had any success in making something like this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To apply the `Timeout` attribute to an assembly, first add the directive `using NUnit.Framework;` to the assembly's `AssemblyInfo.cs`. Then add a line specifying the timeout:

```
[assembly: Timeout(1000)]
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w8c1y2s(v=vs.110).aspx) you can do this using the format you have seen in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
```

You can therefore probably use:

```
[assembly: NUnit.Framework.Timeout(2000)]
```

Although I have not tried this.

This does not need to be in the `AssemblyInfo.cs`, it can be in any file, and if you want to share settings across many assemblies you can define it in one `GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs` and then link this file into every project to use the shared assembly settings.